# C variadic functions va_arg returns wrong double precision

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

So I'm nearly done reimplementing `printf(3)` (I can't use any function that would the conversion for me) in `C`.

Now that I have implemented all the conversions I'm seeing something weird, when I pass my function a `double` to use with say `%g` like `100.10` then `va_arg` gives me `100.09999999999999` so of course my conversion then gives me a string with `100.099999`.

I fetch the double like this:

```
double d = (double)(va_arg(args, double));
```

And I am calling both functions like this:

```
double testd = 100.10;
my_printf("%g", testd); #=> 100.099999
printf("%g", testd); #=> 100.1
```

I *think* that I *know* that the value is wrong because while stepping through the program I'm seeing that `double d = 100.09999999999999`.

Should I do it differently ? Because the real printf seems to be getting the correct value.

EDIT:

```
printf("%#.10g\n", testd); #=> 100.1000000000
```

Is this due to rounding or that maybe the real `printf` is getting the good value ?

Comment: [`100.1` cannot be represented exactly as a floating point value.](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html) `printf` rounds the numbers so it looks pretty. [Just add enough extra digits.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f819d1a4d86fa530)

Comment: The cast is unnecessary. Rather than `double d = (double)(va_arg(args, double));`, just write `double d = va_arg(args, double);`

Comment: Oh ok thanks I thought it was needed!

Comment: @ItsASecret: Nope. `va_arg(args, double)` yields a value of type `double`, and you're using it to initialize an object of type `double`. Why would you need a cast? Even if the LHS and RHS were of different types, all arithmetic types are implicitly convertible. Casts are necessary far more rarely than a lot of people think they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add format specifier, and `printf` will perhaps show the same issue:

```
printf("%0.20g\n", d); // 100.09999999999999 on my system
```

The reason is that in our case the number `100.1` (as most of all numbers) does not have exact binary representation.

Comment: So it's all due to rounding :( thanks. (yeah on mine too I thought 10 was enough)

Comment: Apparently your system's `printf` implementation is clever about rounding inexact values.

Comment: Ah, that's a great answer!